# Prefect Schedule late runs

Tags: python, workflow, schedule, prefect

I have a simple 'Hello world!' code with schedule. But they always start late and yellow rectangles are placed in the graph as shown in the screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOKpU.png)

What is the problem? Why do 'late runs' appear? Аnd how to make green rectangles placed instead of yellow?

```
from prefect import task, Flow
from datetime import timedelta
from prefect.schedules import IntervalSchedule


@task
def say_hello():
    print("Hello, world!")


schedule = IntervalSchedule(interval=timedelta(minutes=1))

with Flow("Hello", schedule=schedule) as flow:
    say_hello()

flow.register(project_name='Lesson')
flow.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what are late runs? Those are flow runs that are scheduled to run but can't move to a Submitted and Running states - i.e., runs that got stuck in a Scheduled state. This issue most commonly occurs due to a mismatch between labels set on your flow's run configuration and those set on your agent. [This Prefect Discourse topic](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/why-is-my-flow-stuck-in-a-scheduled-state/73) dives deeper into the issue. LMK if you have any questions after reading this.